# Programatically protect a RTF file using the Lowagie API?

Tags: java, itext, rtf

I am making RTF file programmatically using iText, "com.lowagie.text.rtf".

Now I need to make my RTF file protected.

Does anyone know how can I do this using the iText API?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at my name. I am Bruno Lowagie and when you say "the lowagie api", you are talking about me.

Allow me to rephrase your question:

> "Can I protect an RTF file created using the iText RTF library?"

The answer to this question is:

> No, you can't protect an RTF file created with that library. That library has been abandoned in 2009. Nobody is working on that library anymore. File-protection isn't supported in that version and won't be supported in the future.

Comment: Thank you sir. We are using this API from long back. We never required to do any major update from last couple of years. As I mentioned, now we need to make content in the file with edit protection. I am not sure if it is possible at all for rtf file? Or do I need to convert my file in .doc or .docx. And if is it possible to do with any open available API?

Comment: I don't know of any open available API that can do this. By the way: such a question is off-topic on StackOverflow.